# How can i use xNet in C# & is there any alternate of xNet in VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

can anyone help me with using xNet in C# ?
1st thing is when i put source code into my c# code tab it partially hide the xNet and says no need of this ?
what should i do? and if i convert my code to vb.net then is there any alternate of xNet using in VB.Net ?
thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNet is a library, so just add a reference to the dll in visual studio. Here's a how to guide for that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

As you are accessing the code as a dll you don't need to worry about what language it is coded in. vb.net and c# can both access the classes it defines.

If you're trying to convert example code which is written in c# to vb.net or vice versa try  using an online conversion tool such as http://converter.telerik.com/

Your description of the issue you're facing with the tabs isn't terribly clear, if you need further help it may pay to upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no XNET support in VB.net or C# at the current time from NI. You can see this by going to the following link below. If you search 'Visual' on that webpage you will find 'Microsoft Visual C/C++ 6.0', which is an old version of Visual Studio ~1998.

http://download.ni.com/support/softlib//embedded%20networks/NI-XNET/Driver/16.0/readme.htm

If someone creates a dll for this then it would be possible, but most likely it is best to request this from NI directly. They should have the capability to support this and release an updated version of the NI-XNET driver software so they can support C# and VB.net.

Hope this helps. I guess the easiest way is to code it in LabVIEW or the harder way is to acquire a copy of Visual Studio C/C++ 6.0 (since they are no longer sold or available).